# What is the proper way to upgrade installed packages with Ansible

Tags: nginx, ansible, ansible-handlers

Let's assume I have the next simple Ansible playbook:

```
---
  tasks:
    - name: Upgrade installed packages
      become: true
      apt:
        upgrade: safe

    - name: Install NGINX web server
      become: true
      apt:
        name: nginx
        state: latest
      notify:
        - Restart NGINX

  handlers:
    - name: Restart NGINX
      become: true
      service:
        name: nginx
        state: restarted
```

As you see, I upgrade installed APT packages first and only then make sure I have the latest Nginx version. The problem is that if there's an update for Nginx, it will be installed in the first task and if so, the second task won't be marked as changed and the handler won't be fired. Is it true? Or Ansible is clever enough to somehow fire this handle only when Nginx was upgraded in the first task?

I wonder about the best practice for this case. Is there a better way than move all the separate installation tasks (which should fire handlers on their change) *before* the task which upgrades all the installed packages?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `state: latest` is already far from best practices, upgrading all packages indiscriminately even farther. The state has to be deterministic, so you should define (tested and accepted) versions only. You'll get only opinion-based answers. I think it should be closed for this reason.

Comment: @techraf Aren't new releases in APT repositories tested and accepted? I think do not upgrade packages at all is not a good practice either. So what is your workflow? How do you handle it with Ansible? Getting good opinion-based answers would be nice too :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not "The Ansible way", but it is an option.

one why you can do it is by using `lsof` to find all the `pid`'s which need restart and pass this information to systemd to get the service name for each pid. And then go over the list of services and restart each one of them.

some one all ready wrote a [perl-script](http://oirase.annexia.org/rwmj.wp.com/needs-restart.pl) like that 
 - see example here: https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/which-services-need-restarting-after-an-upgrade/

another option is but the same is the [restart-services](https://github.com/tpo/debian-goodies/blob/master/restart-services) script from the [debian-goodies](https://github.com/tpo/debian-goodies) repo/package.

Comment: Thanks, it actually answers the question that I need to handle restart by myself and there's no magic by default.

Comment: For now, I'm not aware of any way, but that can be changed easily, if you know how to write Ansible modules, you can extended the current apt/yum/dnf module to iterate over all the updated/changed packages and run the same logic as above.